# Functional equation $3f(-3x) -f(x) = 3x^2$

Tags: functional-equations, inverse-function

> I am trying to solve the following functional equation: $f(x)$ is a continuous function, satisfying 
>   (1) $f(f(x))=x$
>   (2) $ 3f(-3x)-f(x)= 3x^2 $ for $x>0$.

From (1) & (2), I found that $f(x)$ should be decreasing, and $f(x) = f^{-1} (x)$.

But, I cannot figure out how to use (2).

How can I use (2) to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: "From (1), I found that $f(x)$ should be decreasing" What about $f(x)=x$? It satisfies (1) and is increasing.

Comment: Yes, only from (1), $f(x)$ can be the solution. But from (2), if $f(x)=x$ for $x>0$, $f(x)$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: Sure. But it means "From (1), I found that $f(x)$ should be decreasing" is wrong.

Comment: For (2) you have condition $x>0$. Is there any condition for (1)?

Comment: (1) is Babbage's equation with prodigious orbits of solutions. (2) has the particular solution $(3/26)x^2 +a/|x|$, but it may not be easy to fit onto one of those orbits....

Answer (score 1):

**There are no solutions.**

(The question already notes $f$ is decreasing; I include a proof for completeness).

By (1), $f$ is bijective.

Since $f$ is assumed continuous, this implies $f$ is strictly monotone by [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752073). That is, $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Taking the limit as $x\to0^+$ in (2) gives $f(0)=0$. Setting $x=1$ gives
$$
  3f(-3)-f(1)=3.\tag{3}
$$
If $f$ is increasing, then $f(-3)<0$ and $f(1)>0$, contradicting (3). Thus $f$ is decreasing. In particular $f(-3)>0$, so (3) gives
$$
  f(1)=3f(-3)-3>-3.
$$
Thus $1=f(f(1))<f(-3)$. Now (3) gives
$$
  f(1)=3f(-3)-3>0=f(0),
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: (2) is for x>0 , but since f continuous (2) true for x = 0.

Comment: @AntonSorokovskiy Good point, thanks.