# Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be an injective function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be an injective function prove that either $f(0)\le f(x)\le f(1)$  or $f(1)\le f(x)\le f(0)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$

how to start with this problem I really have no idea

Comment: are you missing out any details?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh,, Actuvally I miss where to start this problem

Comment: Are there any additional properties of $f$ stated in the question?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh.. No sir

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -x &, x \in [0,0.5) \\ 2-x &, x\in [0.5,1]\end{cases}$$

Comment: ..what is missing in this question

Comment: any thoughts? which topic are you learning?

Comment: ..continuous is missing?

Comment: that's a good conjecture, try to prove it. =)

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and injective, then by IMVP and Bolzano's theorem you can conclude your result.

Comment: Or see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752073/continuous-injective-map-is-strictly-monotonic