# If $f$ is continuous on $(a,c)$, strictly increasing on $(a,b)$, and strictly decreasing on $(b,c)$, then $f$ is not injective on $(a,c)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Looking for input on, or alternative approaches to, my proof of the following statement:

> Suppose $f$ is continuous on $(a,c)$. Further, for some $b$ satisfying $a \lt b\lt c$, let $f$ be strictly increasing on $(a,b)$ and strictly decreasing on $(b,c)$. Show that $f$ is *not* injective on $(a,c)$.

---

Firstly, by assumption, we must have that for any $x \in (a,b): f(b) \gt f(x)$. Similarly, for any $y \in (b,c): f(b) \gt f(y) \quad (*)$. To see this, consider if $f(b) \leq f(x)$ for some $x \in (a,b)$. This will lead to the contradiction of $f$ not being a strictly increasing function on $(a,b)$ (you can see how this contradiction will similarly arise for $f$ on the interval $(b,c)$ if we assumed $f(b) \leq f(y)$ for some $y \in (b,c)$).

Next, choose an $x \in (a,b)$ and choose a $y \in (b,c)$. Consider the intervals $[x,b]$ and $[b,y]$. $f$ is continous on each of these intervals, which means that there must be a minimum on each of these intervals. By $(*)$, we know that $f$ is strictly increasing on  $[x,b]$ and strictly decreasing on $[b,y]$. Therefore, the minimum point in $[x,b]$ must be $x$, and the minimum point in $[b,y]$ must be $y$. If $f(x)=f(y)$, we are done. So suppose $f(x) \neq f(y)$. Then either $f(x) \lt f(y)$ or $f(y) \lt f(x)$. WLOG (*without loss of generality*), suppose the latter.

By $(*)$, we must have $f(b) \gt f(y) \gt f(x)$. Then, by applying the *Intermediate Value Theorem* to $[x,b]$, we know that there must exist a $z \in (x,b)$ such that $f(z)=f(y)$. Clearly, $z \neq y$ but $f(z)=f(y)$. Therefore, $f$ is not injective on $(a,c)$.

Comment: Seems completely reasonable to me - mind if I ask exactly what WLG stands for? I assume it indicates that similar arguments work for both choices

Comment: WLG = Without Loss of Generality.

Comment: I usually see that written WLOG.

Comment: I agree, WLOG is a more common abbreviation, but I guess one understands from the context what he meant.

Comment: @copper.hat roger that. I'll adopt that convention. Thank you

Comment: I would note that $f(b)$ is the $\max$ on $(a,c)$ and pick some $y \in (\max(f(a),f(c)), f(b)$ and note that there is some $x_1 \in (a,b), x_2 \in (b,c)$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y$.

Comment: @copper.hat: $f$ is only defined on the open interval $(a, c)$. I think that is why the   author introduced $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Proof seems fine. Could probably make it shorter, but depends on how much detail you are expected to give in the proof. For me, the symbol "∧" convinces me enough to move onto the next question.

Comment: Perhaps one should also justify why "strictly increasing on $[x,b)$" plus continuous implies "strictly increasing on $[x,b]$". I also wouldn't say that an interval is increasing—the function is increasing on that interval. Nevertheless a very good solution.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you for the input. I think my "$(*)$" is the result of the of "If $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$ and $f$ is continuous at $b$, then $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b]$". A proof by contradiction would show that if $f(b) \leq f(x)$ for some $x \in (a,b)$, then $f$ is no longer a strictly increasing function on $(a,b)$. Would you agree?

Comment: As a follow-up (always follow up whether your instructor requests it or not):  Give an example of an injective function that satisfies these condititions without the assumption of continuity.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I think $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x &\text{ if } 0 \lt x \lt 1 \\ -x+3 &\text{ if } 1 \leq x \lt 2\end{cases}$$ should work.

Comment: @S.Cramer  Perfect.  One more step.  **Characterize!**   *Theorem.  A continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is injective if and only if $f$ is either ___(?)___ or is ___(?)___.*  Prove that and you have beaten this problem to death, as it deserves.

Comment: Assume $f$ is injective and apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752073/continuous-injective-map-is-strictly-monotonic/1435015#1435015